# How to specify timeout using ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wix, activexobject

In my WiX installer I am making an HTTP call using an ActiveXObject with the following code:

```
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
xmlhttp.open('GET', url, false);
xmlhttp.send();
var strResponse = xmlhttp.ResponseText;
```

Is there any way to specify a **timeout** on this call? It seems to default to 10 seconds but I'm looking to extend this.

I know this is the way to do HTTP calls in IE versions 5 and lower so I think there should be a way but I can't find many resources dating back that far.

Comment: Are you working with HTAs?

Comment: Nope, this is executed in a WiX Custom Action